# Customizable email with domain name

Tags: email

i'm a student and I have as a project the creation of university website. My problem is located at the creation of messaging box with customizable email for Example : **example@domainname.univ**.

Comment: Your problem is not clear. Could you tell us the programming language being used and copy the part of your code with the problem ?

Comment: @Elektordi I am at the research stage, still can't find how to create a messaging system or an email service like gmail to my website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like what you need is to host a mail server alongside your website.

Read more here https://www.linode.com/docs/email/running-a-mail-server/